# Gazebo Plugin for 6D velocity.. Error

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I got the following error suddenly in otherwise working code. the error doesnt show when a plugin is not included however thats not the solution.

```
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[plugin], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <link>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error [parser.cc:299] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [World.cc:1469] Unable to read sdf string
```

My gazebo plugin section is

```
<gazebo reference="base_footprint">
      <plugin name="3d_vel_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros3d.so">
        <robotNamespace>quad</robotNamespace>
        <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
        <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
        <odometryFrame>map</odometryFrame>
        <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
        <odometryRate>20</odometryRate>
      </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

and my plugin looks as follows

```
#include "/home/saroj/gazebo_plugin/gazebo_ros3d.h"
#include <cmath>

namespace gazebo 
{

  GazeboRos3DMove::GazeboRos3DMove() {}

  GazeboRos3DMove::~GazeboRos3DMove() {}

  // Load the controller
  void GazeboRos3DMove::Load(physics::ModelPtr parent, 
      sdf::ElementPtr sdf) 
  {

    parent_ = parent;

    /* Parse parameters */

    robot_namespace_ = "";
    if (!sdf->HasElement("robotNamespace")) 
    {
      ROS_INFO("3DMovePlugin missing <robotNamespace>, "
          "defaults to \"%s\"", robot_namespace_.c_str());
    }
    else 
    {
      robot_namespace_ = 
        sdf->GetElement("robotNamespace")->Get<std::string>();
    }

    command_topic_ = "cmd_vel";
    if (!sdf->HasElement("commandTopic")) 
    {
      ROS_WARN("3DMovePlugin (ns = %s) missing <commandTopic>, "
          "defaults to \"%s\"", 
          robot_namespace_.c_str(), command_topic_.c_str());
    } 
    else 
    {
      command_topic_ = sdf->GetElement("commandTopic")->Get<std::string>();
    }

    odometry_topic_ = "odom";
    if (!sdf->HasElement("odometryTopic")) 
    {
      ROS_WARN("3DMovePlugin (ns = %s) missing <odometryTopic>, "
          "defaults to \"%s\"", 
          robot_namespace_.c_str(), odometry_topic_.c_str());
    } 
    else 
    {
      odometry_topic_ = sdf->GetElement("odometryTopic")->Get<std::string>();
    }

    odometry_frame_ = "odom";
    if (!sdf->HasElement("odometryFrame")) 
    {
      ROS_WARN("3DMovePlugin (ns = %s) missing <odometryFrame>, "
          "defaults to \"%s\"",
          robot_namespace_.c_str(), odometry_frame_.c_str());
    }
    else 
    {
      odometry_frame_ = sdf->GetElement("odometryFrame")->Get<std::string>();
    }

    robot_base_frame_ = "base_footprint";
    if (!sdf->HasElement("robotBaseFrame")) 
    {
      ROS_WARN("3DMovePlugin (ns = %s) missing <robotBaseFrame>, "
          "defaults to \"%s\"",
          robot_namespace_.c_str(), robot_base_frame_.c_str());
    } 
    else 
    {
      robot_base_frame_ = sdf->GetElement("robotBaseFrame")->Get<std::string>();
    } 

    odometry_rate_ = 20.0;
    if (!sdf->HasElement("odometryRate")) 
    {
      ROS_WARN("3DMovePlugin (ns = %s) missing <odometryRate>, "
          "defaults to %f",
          robot_namespace_.c_str(), odometry_rate_);
    } 
    else 
    {
      odometry_rate_ = sdf->GetElement("odometryRate")->Get<double>();
    } 
 
    last_odom_publish_time_ = parent_->GetWorld()->GetSimTime();
    last_odom_pose_ = parent_->GetWorldPose();
    x_ = 0;
    y_ = 0;
    z_ = 0;
    rot_x_ = 0;
    rot_y_ = 0;
    rot_z_ = 0;
    alive_ = true;

    // Ensure that ROS has been initialized and subscribe to cmd_vel
    if (!ros::isInitialized()) 
    {
      ROS_FATAL_STREAM("3DMovePlugin (ns = " << robot_namespace_
        << "). A ROS node for Gazebo has not been initialized, "
        << "unable to load plugin. Load the Gazebo system plugin "
        << "'libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so' in the gazebo_ros package)");
      return;
    }
    rosnode_.reset(new ros::NodeHandle(robot_namespace_));

    ROS_DEBUG("OCPlugin (%s) has started!", 
        robot_namespace_.c_str());

    tf_prefix_ = tf::getPrefixParam(*rosnode_);
    transform_broadcaster_.reset(new tf::TransformBroadcaster());

    // subscribe to the odometry topic
    ros::SubscribeOptions so =
      ros::SubscribeOptions::create<geometry_msgs::Twist>(command_topic_, 1,
          boost::bind(&GazeboRos3DMove::cmdVelCallback, this, _1),
          ros::VoidPtr(), &queue_);

    vel_sub_ = rosnode_->subscribe(so);
    odometry_pub_ = rosnode_->advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>(odometry_topic_, 1);

    // start custom queue for diff drive
    callback_queue_thread_ = 
      boost::thread(boost::bind(&GazeboRos3DMove::QueueThread, this));

    // listen to the update event (broadcast every simulation iteration)
    update_connection_ = 
      event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
          boost::bind(&GazeboRos3DMove::UpdateChild, this));

  }

  // Update the controller
  void GazeboRos3DMove::UpdateChild() 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(lock);
    math::Pose pose = parent_->GetWorldPose();
    float phi = pose.rot.GetRoll();
    float theta = pose.rot.GetPitch();
    float psi = pose.rot.GetYaw();
    
    parent_->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3(x_*cosf(theta)*cosf(psi) + y_*(sinf(phi)*sinf(theta)*cosf(psi)-cosf(phi)*sinf(psi)) + z_*(cosf(phi)*sinf(theta)*cosf(psi)+sinf(phi)*sinf(psi)), 
          x_*cosf(theta)*sinf(psi) + y_*(sinf(phi)*sinf(theta)*sinf(psi)+cosf(phi)*cosf(psi)) + z_*(cosf(phi)*sinf(theta)*sinf(psi)-sinf(phi)*cosf(psi)), 
          x_*(-sinf(theta)) + y_*sinf(phi)*cosf(theta) + z_*cosf(phi)*cosf(theta)));
          
          
    parent_->SetAngularVel(math::Vector3(
            //  rot_x_ + rot_y_*sinf(phi)*tanf(theta) + rot_z_*cosf(phi)*tanf(theta),
            //  rot_y_ * cosf(phi) + rot_z_*(-sinf(theta)),
            //  rot_y_ * sinf(phi)/cosf(theta) + rot_z_*cosf(phi)/cosf(theta)));
                rot_x_,
                rot_y_,
                rot_z_));
            
                
    if (odometry_rate_ > 0.0) {
      common::Time current_time = parent_->GetWorld()->GetSimTime();
      double seconds_since_last_update = 
        (current_time - last_odom_publish_time_).Double();
      if (seconds_since_last_update > (1.0 / odometry_rate_)) {
        publishOdometry(seconds_since_last_update);
        last_odom_publish_time_ = current_time;
      }
    }
  }

  // Finalize the controller
  void GazeboRos3DMove::FiniChild() {
    alive_ = false;
    queue_.clear();
    queue_.disable();
    rosnode_->shutdown();
    callback_queue_thread_.join();
  }

  void GazeboRos3DMove::cmdVelCallback(
      const geometry_msgs::Twist::ConstPtr& cmd_msg) 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(lock);
    x_ = cmd_msg->linear.x;
    y_ = cmd_msg->linear.y;
    z_ = cmd_msg->linear.z;
    rot_x_ = cmd_msg->angular.x;
    rot_y_ = cmd_msg->angular.y;
    rot_z_ = cmd_msg->angular.z;
  }

  void GazeboRos3DMove::QueueThread() 
  {
    static const double timeout = 0.01;
    while (alive_ && rosnode_->ok()) 
    {
      queue_.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
    }
  }

  void GazeboRos3DMove::publishOdometry(double step_time) 
  {

    ros::Time current_time = ros::Time::now();
    std::string odom_frame = tf::resolve(tf_prefix_, odometry_frame_);
    std::string base_footprint_frame = 
      tf::resolve(tf_prefix_, robot_base_frame_);

    // getting data for base_footprint to odom transform
    math::Pose pose = this->parent_->GetWorldPose();

    tf::Quaternion qt(pose.rot.x, pose.rot.y, pose.rot.z, pose.rot.w);
    tf::Vector3 vt(pose.pos.x, pose.pos.y, pose.pos.z);

    tf::Transform base_footprint_to_odom(qt, vt);
    transform_broadcaster_->sendTransform(
        tf::StampedTransform(base_footprint_to_odom, current_time, odom_frame,
            base_footprint_frame));

    // publish odom topic
    odom_.pose.pose.position.x = pose.pos.x;
    odom_.pose.pose.position.y = pose.pos.y;

    odom_.pose.pose.orientation.x = pose.rot.x;
    odom_.pose.pose.orientation.y = pose.rot.y;
    odom_.pose.pose.orientation.z = pose.rot.z;
    odom_.pose.pose.orientation.w = pose.rot.w;
    odom_.pose.covariance[0] = 0.00001;
    odom_.pose.covariance[7] = 0.00001;
    odom_.pose.covariance[14] = 1000000000000.0;
    odom_.pose.covariance[21] = 1000000000000.0;
    odom_.pose.covariance[28] = 1000000000000.0;
    odom_.pose.covariance[35] = 0.001;

    // get velocity in /odom frame
    math::Vector3 linear;
    linear.x = (pose.pos.x - last_odom_pose_.pos.x) / step_time;
    linear.y = (pose.pos.y - last_odom_pose_.pos.y) / step_time;
    linear.z = (pose.pos.z - last_odom_pose_.pos.z) / step_time;
    if (rot_x_ > M_PI / step_time) 
    { 
      // we cannot calculate the angular velocity correctly
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.x = rot_x_;
      
    } 
    else 
    {
      float last_roll = last_odom_pose_.rot.GetRoll();
      float current_roll = pose.rot.GetRoll();
      while (current_roll < last_roll - M_PI) current_roll += 2 * M_PI;
      while (current_roll > last_roll + M_PI) current_roll -= 2 * M_PI;
      float angular_diff_roll = current_roll - last_roll;
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.x = angular_diff_roll / step_time;
     }
    
     if (rot_y_ > M_PI / step_time) 
    { 
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.y = rot_y_;
    } 
    else 
    {
      float last_pitch = last_odom_pose_.rot.GetPitch();
      float current_pitch = pose.rot.GetPitch();
      while (current_pitch < last_pitch - M_PI) current_pitch += 2 * M_PI;
      while (current_pitch > last_pitch + M_PI) current_pitch -= 2 * M_PI;
      float angular_diff_pitch = current_pitch - last_pitch;
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.y = angular_diff_pitch / step_time;
    }
    
     if (rot_z_ > M_PI / step_time) 
    { 
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.z = rot_z_;
    } 
    else 
    {
      float last_yaw = last_odom_pose_.rot.GetYaw();
      float current_yaw = pose.rot.GetYaw();
      while (current_yaw < last_yaw - M_PI) current_yaw += 2 * M_PI;
      while (current_yaw > last_yaw + M_PI) current_yaw -= 2 * M_PI;
      float angular_diff_yaw = current_yaw - last_yaw;
      odom_.twist.twist.angular.z = angular_diff_yaw / step_time;
    }
    
    last_odom_pose_ = pose;

    // convert velocity to child_frame_id (aka base_footprint)
    float phi = pose.rot.GetRoll();
    float theta = pose.rot.GetPitch();
    float psi = pose.rot.GetYaw();
    
    
    odom_.twist.twist.linear.x = cosf(theta)*cosf(psi) * linear.x + cosf(theta)*sinf(psi) * linear.y - sinf(theta)*linear.z;
    odom_.twist.twist.linear.y = (sinf(phi)*sinf(theta)*cosf(psi)-cosf(phi)*sinf(psi)) * linear.x + (sinf(phi)*sinf(theta)*sinf(psi)+cosf(phi)*cosf(psi))* linear.y + sinf(phi)*cosf(theta)*linear.z;
    odom_.twist.twist.linear.z = (cosf(phi)*sinf(theta)*cosf(psi)+sinf(phi)*sinf(psi))*linear.x + (cosf(phi)*sinf(theta)*sinf(psi)-sinf(phi)*cosf(psi)) * linear.y + cosf(phi)*cosf(theta)*linear.z;

    odom_.header.stamp = current_time;
    odom_.header.frame_id = odom_frame;
    odom_.child_frame_id = base_footprint_frame;

    odometry_pub_.publish(odom_);
  }

  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(GazeboRos3DMove)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4592/gazebo-plugin-for-6d-velocity..-error/) by [espee](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/513/espee/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This error:

```
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[plugin], child of element[link] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[link]
```

says that a plugin cannot be attached to a link. You have to attach the plugin to a model.

Change your gazebo reference to:

```
<gazebo reference="model_name">
 ...
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [espee](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/513/espee/) on 2013-10-07**:
Thanks a lot. Its working now.

**Comment by [anonymous](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/957/anonymous/) on 2014-10-10**:
hi , is your transform_broadcaster running properly ? Actually i have also developed he same code as yours but it is showing error undefined symbol transform _broadcaster. I think it is a compilation error , but I am not able to solve it . Can you plz suggest me any solution .Thanks!